# CSS: How to avoid line break before inline-block element?

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
div {
  font-size: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-70px);
}
```

```html
<div>My Text<span>&nbsp;2021</span></div>
```

If the window size gets smaller, then it can happen that `2021` stands alone in one line. But the line should never break like that, only after `My`. So it should work like that: `My<possible break>Text<never a break>&nbsp;2021`.

How is it possible to code that? Is there an easier way than using a `white-space` container around?

If I use `inline` instead of `inline-block`, it generally works, but then this `translateY` is not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: To the `2021` you can use `<sup>2021</sup>` tag instead of translateY

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to control the font size and space around this "sup" manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the width of span equal to 0 and add some padding to the container

```css
div {
  font-size: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 65px; /* here */
}

div span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; /* here */
  font-size: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-70px);
}
```

```html
<div>My Text<span>&nbsp;2021</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combo of `position:relative` and `position:absolute` and have more granular control over the position of `span` using `top,left,right,bottom` or `transform:translate` variants, whatever works for you.

I have used `translateY` to get the desired result :-

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 130px;
  position:relative;
}

div span {
  position:absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  transform:translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div>My Text<span>&nbsp;2021</span></div>
```

Comment: Thaaanksssssssss